# HTML 5 Play video file in mp4

Tags: html

I am using HTML 5 to play a video. The video file is on another drive from where my application is at. Currently the video files are on the E drive.

```
       <video width="640" height="480" controls="controls">
         <source src="E:/Video/part1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />   
      </video>
```

I tried the what I have above but not working.

I also tried:

```
    <source src="E://Video/part1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

but that did not work as well. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does anything appear? Are you getting any error? Or is it just a blank space where the <video> would appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but my best guess would be to either:

## Upload it

Upload the file to a online host/storage.

## Possible fix

try doing `<source src="file:///E:/Video/part1.mp4" type="video/mp4">`

## Possible Fix 2

make sure that the drive src is at `file:///E:/Video/part1.mp4"` and not at `file:///E:/video/PaRt1.MP4` (e.g.) as it might be CaSe-SeNsItIve.

Comment: Windows almost never uses case sensitive file systems. Almost nothing except Windows uses letters to identify drives.

Comment: Okay, well try adding the `file:///E:/Video/part1.mp4"` because (i.e.), opening a file from your computer in a browser would be the location itself (E:/Video/part1.mp4) but then adds "file:///destination" before it, so try that. Because I'm thinking it would be reading it as that.

Comment: If all else fails, try doing the first solution.